# SQL SELECT Duplicate Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using this Query but I have it wrong...

```
SELECT * FROM [Orders]
JOIN [Customers]
ON [Orders].[CustomerID] = [Customers].[CustomerID]
WHERE [Orders].[OrderDate] BETWEEN '2010/1/1' AND '2011/1/1'
AND [Orders].[Total] > 1
```

I'm getting a Duplicate Column name error for CustomerID. I'm not sure how to use an Alias for this to work.

Could someone show me how to write it correctly.

EDIT:

Thanks for all the suggestions, here's what I can out with.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Orders.CustomerID, Orders.ShipToID, Orders.ShipName, Orders.ShipAddress, Orders.ShipAddress2, Orders.ShipCity, Orders.ShipStateOrProvince, Orders.ShipPostalCode, Orders.Total, Orders.OrderDate, Customers.Profession
FROM Orders
JOIN Customers
ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID
WHERE Orders.OrderDate BETWEEN '4/3/2010' AND '2/20/2011'
AND Orders.Total > 1
```

Thanks Again!

Comment: Please don't use `SELECT *` in production code; name your columns. Please read https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list.aspx

Comment: @AaronBertrand Great advice (and a very nice article, by the way).  There's no indication in the post that this is production code though.  Could just be testing =)

Comment: @jadarnel27 sure, but not using `SELECT *` still helps alleviate the issue - at least then you have control over aliases.

Comment: Also, I strongly recommend against using regional formats for date literals like `'yyyy/m/d'` - I have an article for that too: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mishandling-date-range-queries.aspx

Comment: @AaronBertrand That's true, that would have avoided the problem altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be explicit about the columns you're selecting, rather than `SELECT *`, and when you must get a similarly named column from both tables, use an alias.

```
SELECT
  Orders.OrderID,
  /* alias example, not that you'd need both CustomerID columns */
  Orders.CustomerID AS oCustomerID,
  Customer.CustomerID AS cCustomerID,
  Customers.Name,
  Customers.Address,
  ....
  ....
FROM [Orders]
JOIN [Customers]
ON [Orders].[CustomerID] = [Customers].[CustomerID]
WHERE [Orders].[OrderDate] BETWEEN '2010/1/1' AND '2011/1/1'
AND [Orders].[Total] > 1
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT [Orders].* FROM [Orders] ...
```

To only get the columns from the Orders table. Or skip the `*` altogether and write explicitly which columns you want.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify a table at the beginning to avoid that error:

```
SELECT [Orders].* FROM [Orders]
```

If you do want **every column from both tables**, you will have to list them all out separately and alias the duplicate `CustomerID` columns.

```
SELECT 
    [Orders].CustomerID AS oCustID, 
    [Customers].CustomerID AS cCustID, 
    [Orders].anotherColumn,
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to reference all the columns you want explicity rather than using *.

eg

```
SELECT 
   C.ID, 
   O.ID 
FROM 
   [Orders] O
   JOIN [Customers] C
     ON O.[CustomerID] = C.[CustomerID]
WHERE 
   O.[OrderDate] BETWEEN '2010/1/1' AND '2011/1/1'
   AND O.[Total] > 1
```

Comment: I think you'll still want to give those columns aliases. Whatever is detecting duplicate columns is not going to care which table a column came from, it's still going to see two columns named `ID` in the resultset.